# Trouble updating attributes of a layer based on another layer's attributes if features intersect in python, QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, intersection, fields-attributes

I am trying to assign attributes from features in one layer that intersect features in another layer. When I run my code, I do not get an errors but it does not update the attribute field as I am expecting. I wrote my code based on the example in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506358/pyqgis-for-spatial-join. It appears as though the program does not see that any features intersect, but when i compare them on the map canvas, they do. I'm not sure what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
GPSDegLyr.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('UniqueID',QVariant.Int)])
GPSDegLyr.updateFields()

idxGPS = GPSDegLyr.fieldNameIndex('UniqueID')
idxBuff = dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84.fieldNameIndex('UniqueID')

GPSDegLyr.startEditing()

for b in dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84.getFeatures():
    for g in GPSDegLyr.getFeatures():
        if g.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()) == True:
            val = b.attributes()[idxBuff]
            print val
            g.setAttribute(idxGPS,val)
            GPSDegLyr.updateFeature(g)

    GPSDegLyr.commitChanges()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(GPSDegLyr)
```

UPDATE: I solved the intersecting problem - now the programs sees the intersections and prints the values. But still doesn't write the values out to the attrribute table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the indentation of the commitChanges line - it should have been dedented.